# whats the difference between using `waitForKeyElements` and JQuery `.on()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

whats the difference between using `waitForKeyElements` and JQuery `.on()` ?

like in the **adapted** example below, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53839921/982924

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _delete Adblock blocking nodes
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements ("[id$='adblockinfo']", killNode);

function killNode (elem) {
    elem.remove();
}
```

but i usually do something like

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _delete Adblock blocking nodes
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

elem = $('#killme')

$(document).on('load ready', elem, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

given the author's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) experience in javascript, he certainly knows what he is doing.
but i still would like to learn about the differences between the two techniques.

---

> Given the name and usage, waitForKeyElements will ... well ... wait
>   (and keep waiting) until those elements are available. While your
>   doc.on(ready) can easily be bypassed with a setTimeout or ajax load.
>   In addition, waitForKeyElements polls the DOM for the elements (every
>   300ms from the source) while .on(load) will fire immediately. –
>   freedomn-m

feel free to correct me on this:
i could mimic this behavior by just removing the selector, so the entire document and its descendants would be monitored.

as in

```
elem = $('#killme')

$(document).on('load ready', function() {
    elem.remove();
});
```

that's what i understood from https://api.jquery.com/on/

**If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.**

Comment: Given the name and usage, waitForKeyElements will ... well ... wait (and keep waiting) until those elements are available.  While your doc.on(ready) can easily be bypassed with a setTimeout or ajax load.  In addition, waitForKeyElements *polls* the DOM for the elements (every 300ms from the source) while `.on(load)` will fire immediately.

Comment: That's fine, but adding HTML dom elements *don't* raise load/ready events.  `$("#mydiv").append("<div id='newdiv'>")` won't fire load/ready but waitforkeyelements will find #newdiv the next time it polls.

Comment: As per @Rory's answer - waitForKeyElements is a (simplistic) replacement for MutationObserver, not for load/ready event.

Comment: "load" is only fired when elements that have something to load finish loading the something. For example, images, iframes, and the window. "ready" only waits for DOMReady, there is only one DOMReady, it isn't something individual elements have. jQuery has literally no functionality that would match what the given code is doing.

Comment: @KevinB does `load` even fire on elements which aren't `document` or `img` any more?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it can... if it's triggered in a way that would make them bubble. but by default no

Comment: Turn them into answers if you wish, i do not contribute actual answers here anymore.

Comment: @KevinB yep, thought I'd test it myself: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/wzds9871/

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source of [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/zapu/cb24cce69a180df81e12) you can see how it works.

In simple terms it places the callback function you provide in a `setInterval()` which runs every 300ms. Within this interval it checks the DOM to see if the selector you provided exists. When the element is created it executes your callback.

This is different from jQuery's `on()` method as that is for binding to *events* which are raised from elements which are dynamically created. It does not do anything when the new element is actually created.

With regard to the implementation of `waitForKeyElements`, it is far from an ideal solution for a variety of reasons, not least of which is performance. If you need to know when a dynamic element has been created use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: could you please check my edited question? right at the end.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. `on()` and `waitForKeyElements()` do completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m

Given the name and usage, waitForKeyElements will ... well ... wait (and keep waiting) until those elements are available. While your doc.on(ready) can easily be bypassed with a setTimeout or ajax load. In addition, waitForKeyElements polls the DOM for the elements (every 300ms from the source) while .on(load) will fire immediately. – freedomn-m

adding HTML dom elements don't raise load/ready events. $("#mydiv").append("") won't fire load/ready but waitforkeyelements will find #newdiv the next time it polls. – freedomn-m

As per @Rory's answer - waitForKeyElements is a (simplistic) replacement for MutationObserver, not for load/ready event. – freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin B

"load" is only fired when elements that have something to load finish loading the something. For example, images, iframes, and the window. "ready" only waits for DOMReady, there is only one DOMReady, it isn't something individual elements have. jQuery has literally no functionality that would match what the given code is doing. – Kevin B

does load even fire on elements which aren't document or img any more? – Rory McCrossan

it can... if it's triggered in a way that would make them bubble. but by default no – Kevin B

Turn them into answers if you wish, i do not contribute actual answers here anymore. – Kevin B